# Estruturar Array vindo de mysql com PDO (organizar)

Tags: php, mysql, array, pdo

Boa noite, estou com uma dificuldade com arrays onde gostaria que eles ficassem na ordem para que eu possa os utilizar da seguinte forma.

Em meu banco de dados possuo muitas imagens que eu as chamo com este código abaixo.

```
<?php $image_search = 00001::conect_sql();

$image_search = $image_search -> prepare("SELECT img_page, img_title, img_url FROM images ORDER BY img_id ASC");
$image_search -> execute();
$image_search = $image_search -> fetchAll();

foreach($image_search as $key => $img_link) { } ?>
```

Com este código eu consigo listar todas as imagens sem problemas algum, mas o que eu gostaria de fazer é criar um array com a estrutura abaixo.

```
id | title | link
0 | título da imagem 1 | link da imagem 1
1 | título da imagem 2 | link da imagem 2
```

e assim em diante, como no caso em um array que ficaria

```
[0] => [img_title] - [img_url]
[1] => [img_title] - [img_url]
```

o por que de eu querer fazer isso é para poder usar a variável $img_link em um echo em qualquer lugar do script utilizando a seguinte formatação.

```
echo $img_link[0][img_title] - $img_link[0][img_title]

echo $img_link[1][img_title] - $img_link[1][img_title]

echo $img_link[2][img_title]
echo $img_link[3][img_title]
```

onde eu escolherei qual imagem utilizar apenas mudando o número da chave [X]

---

Consegui mais ou menos com este código

```
 $img_page_name[] = array($img_link['img_url']);
```

dentro do foreach

então com este

```
<?php echo $img_page_name[0][0];?>
```

no lugar que desejo que a imagem apareça.

Existe alguma forma melhor de fazer isso?
uma coisa legal seria também se funcionar um if na hora de pegar a imagem, cada imagem tem um img_page no caso, na img_page = home só exibiria a última img_url que tem a img_page igual a home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara faz um array bidimensional, é um array principal com vários arrays de duas posições dentro. vou tentar exemplificar usando sua query:

```
<?php 

$imageSearch = 00001::conect_sql();

$imageSearch = $imageSearch -> prepare("SELECT img_page, img_title, img_url FROM images ORDER BY img_id ASC");
$imageSearch -> execute();
$imageSearch = $imageSearch -> fetchAll();

$ordena = [];
foreach($imageSearch as $key => $img) {
    $ordena['titulo'][] = $img['img_title'];
    $ordena['url'][] = $img['img_url'];
} 
print_r($ordena); 
/** A saída será uma lista de array com duas posições onde estas serão titulo e url com as colunas que você retornou do banco.
**/
?>
```

Eu não me recordo agora se o PDO retorna um array ou um objeto, mas o print_r na variável que retorna a tua consulta já te informa o tipo retornado se for objeto acesse os valores da variável como objeto ex: $img->img_title; $img->img_url;

Espero que ajude cara, se ajudar não esquece de aceitar a resposta.

Comment: testarei assim que chegar do trabalho e lhe dou o feedback, mas parece funcionar.